# Calling a GET Rest service using apiClient from my java application. If I have '&' as part of input param. Its taking it as separator

Tags: java, rest, get, swagger, swagger-codegen

I am consuming a GET Rest API. I have imported the client api and using it to call the service. If I have & as part of input like `"1 & 2"`. Its not getting encoded and the source is receiving the param as just 1. When I use swagger ui to call the same method its working fine.

I am completely new to web-services. Please let me know If I missed some necessary details for everybody to understand my problem. We are using swagger code-gen to generate client api.

```
String code = "1 & 2";

String productId = productControllerApi.getAllProductIdUsingGET(null, null, null, code);
```

What should I do so that `getAllProductIdUsingGET` receives parameter as `1 & 2`?

I tried

```
URLEncoder.encode(code, CharEncoding.UTF_8);
```

but now  `getAllProductIdUsingGET` receives parameter as `1+%26+vikram` and don't give me the necessary output.

Is there anything I can do at the consumer side or is it the source that has to handle?

Comment: *I have imported the client api and using it to call the service* Show us the code of this API.

Comment: Have you tried using postman or any other rest client? I tried with postman 1%26vikram, it is working as expected. Decoding param before sending and verify in server side( in your received param '+' symbol is there).

Comment: @LutzHorn Its the client api generated by the source service using swagger-codegen-cli

Comment: @SuseendranP From Postman and swagger UI. Its working fine. I have given encoded input and it works just fine. But I add the dependency compile(group: 'com.xyz.ab', name: 'product-service', version: '0.1.10.1-prod-del-fix-SNAPSHOT', classifier: 'clientApi'). Import it where I want to call and do this productControllerApi.getAllProductIdUsingGET(null, null, null, code); But here event in encode the input, its not working..

Answer (score 0):

You should send encoded String to Rest API, and then use:

```
String decoded = java.net.URLDecoder.decode(code , "UTF-8");
String productId = productControllerApi.getAllProductIdUsingGET(null, null, null, decoded);
```

Comment: When I do this, Its taking productId = 1 as input. It is supposed to be 1 & 2